# Wordpress get_option and update_option

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I do have a problem regarding the plug-in settings that I've made.

I've created a simple textbox and a submit button and run it on the admin page setting. The name of the textbox and submit button is myfirst_plugin.php. Now all I just want is to fill the field and when you refresh it, it'll show the last attributes that you entered on the name, email, comments etc. Would that be possible? How can I use the get_option and update_option?

For example, on the name field I type the name “Jayson Parker”, if I am going to refresh it again, Jayson Parker would be on the name field even if I refresh it.

```
    <?php
/*
Plugin Name: Wordpress Event Plugin
Plugin URI:
Description: plugin for wordpress
Version: 1.0
Author:
Author URI:jayson.parker@gmail.com
License: GPLv2
*/

// Admin Page

    add_action('admin_menu', 'myfirstplugin_admin_actions');

    function myfirstplugin_admin_actions() {
        add_options_page(
            "Event Settings",
            "Event Settings",
            'manage_options',
            "wp_event_plugin",
            "myfirstplugin_admin_page"
        );


    }

     function myfirstplugin_admin_page() {
        include("myfirst_plugin.php");
    }



    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of my plugin:

```
$dmd_posts = $_POST['post'];
$dmd_pages = $_POST['page'];
$dmd_searchbox = $_POST['searchbox'];
$dmd_formidable = $_POST['formidable'];

$dmd_setting_values = $dmd_posts.','.$dmd_pages.','.$dmd_searchbox.','.$dmd_formidable;

saveMethod($dmd_setting_values);



function saveMethod($dmd_setting_values){
    if(!get_option('dmd-pages-settings')){
        add_option('dmd-pages-settings', $dmd_setting_values);
    }else{
        update_option('dmd-pages-settings', $dmd_setting_values);
    }
    return true;
```

Here some references of wordpress:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option

Comment: may i know if what kind of plugin is these?

Comment: is it the same like if you refresh the plugin it will show the last entered value?

Comment: yup i check for the references and it's look simple. but i am new in wordpress and this is my first assignment, i dunno where to place. thankyou

Comment: You have one mainfile in your plugin. There you can input your add_option, get_option.

Comment: yup . the one i posted is the mainfile of the plug in

Comment: i wonder how can i put the get post and update option on the mainfile , i am confused sir regarding to the textbox that i made. "myFirst_plugin.php" .its just a simple textbox and submit , i wonder how can i show the last entered value of the text even if i refresh it.